# Find out which theme is loaded in a given page

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to do some theming for Drupal 8 and I was trying to understand what theme is being used on a given page. I remember using theme developer module in Drupal 7, and using `dpm()` of the page array after theme developer started having issues.

How can I achieve the same with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal 8, you can do two things from custom code:

```
\Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();

\Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
```

The first will return a theme object, the second will return just the theme name.

See the [ThemeManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/class/ThemeManager/8.2.x) docs for more details.

You can also install Devel/WebProfiler for more information about the current page request and other variables.

Answer (score 0):

[Global theme variables got replaced by an ActiveTheme in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2324935).

In Drupal 7 you could access and set the current active theme via global variables like `$GLOBALS['theme_key']` and `$GLOBALS['theme']`.

In Drupal 8 this is replaced by an ActiveTheme object available via the 'theme.manager' service:

Example code in Drupal 7:

```
drupal_set_message(t("Active theme name: @name", array('@name' => $GLOBALS['theme_key'])));
```

Code in Drupal 8:

```
drupal_set_message(t("Active theme name: @name", array('@name' => \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName())));
```

On top of the theme name the ActiveTheme (`\Drupal\Core\Theme\ActiveTheme`) object provides all runtime information needed about the active theme, like the path to the active theme: